# Magento - Function name must be a string

Tags: javascript, php, magento, google-ads-api

I am trying to pass revenue data to AdWords from Magento by adding some PHP code to the site, then implementing the tracking with an echo to carry the variable over to the Javascript.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$total = (float)number_format($order()->getSubtotal(),2);
?>
```

Then after this, I am using a PHP echo to take the $total into the Google conversion tracking code like this:

```
    <!-- Google Code for Website Conversions Conversion Page --> <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1011076746;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "3B7tCPfZj2YQip2P4gM"; 
if (<?php echo $total?>) {
    var google_conversion_value = <?php echo $total?>;
}
var google_conversion_currency = "USD"; 
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""  
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1011076746/?value=<?php echo $total?>&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;label=3B7tCPfZj2YQip2P4gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

But no luck.

It returns a Function name must be a string error on line 69. Line 69 is the 4th line down in my code, as far as I know. I had to remove it per the client's request.

Can anyone help please? I am not experienced enough with PHP to really diagnose this one.

Comment: Removing parenthesis after $order in `$total = (float)number_format($order()->getSubtotal(),2);` solve it?

Comment: @Yes you are using a `$variable` as a Function which is wrong..!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are using `$variable` as a `function myFunction()` in your code which is wrong.

**Note :** Variables & Functions are two different main elements of every programming language so it's better to at least differentiate between these two and never mistake taking one for another.!

**Solution :** Remove the Parentheses `()` after `$order` in your following code and your problem will be solved.!

**CODE :**

```
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$total = (float)number_format($order->getSubtotal(),2);
?>
```

**@Actual Credit Goes To @Felippe Duarte**

### EXTRA LESSON :

A Variable can hold a function i.e You can assign a function to a variable and then later you can call that function just right away using the variable.

**For Instance :**

```
//It's A Function
function myFunction() {
// Simple Printing The Hello World Text
echo "Hello World";
}
// Assigning The Function To The Variable
$variable = 'myFunction';
//Calling The Variable As A Function
echo $variable();
```

Comment: You can [have a variable hold a function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) `$variable=function(){}`, and [have a variable contain the name of a function and be able to call it](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php): `function t(){}; $t2='t'; $t2();`

Comment: @PatrickEvans : Yup...That's Right..! You can assign a function to a variable and then you can call the function through the variable..!

Comment: @PatrickEvans :It's indeed a very nice trick to call a `function` from a `$variable` from what I am assuming the `$variable` is just printed instead while the `()` make the function call ???

Comment: I will try this and if it works assign as best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok..No Problem...You can let me know if you are experiencing any problem after applying my code..!